# Difference in handling datetime between pandas and matplotlib plot ( mdates )

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple data frame that looks like like this where the index type is datetime64[ns].

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


df = (pd.DataFrame( np.random.rand(20,4), index = pd.date_range(start = "2000-05-31",end = "2020-05-31",freq = "Y"), columns =["a","b","c","d"])).cumsum()

# The following code looks OK
fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize = (15,10) )
fig.set_facecolor("white")
ax.plot(df.index, df )
ax.minorticks_on()        
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.show()


# The following code looks not OK
fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize = (15,10) )
fig.set_facecolor("white")
df.plot(ax = ax  ) 
ax.minorticks_on()        
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.show()
```

I was expecting the above two code blocks generate almost identical charts. But, that is not the case. The first block gives me what I am expecting. The x-axis ticks look right.

The chart created by the second graph does not have any x-axis ticks at all. This tells me that somehow `mdates.YearLocator()` is not working for pandas built in dataframe plot. However, I have no idea how to fix it.

I am looking for an explanation on how they are handled differently, and a solution to modify second code block so that it works.

Picture generated by the first code block.
[image]

Picture generated by the second code block.
[image]

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that `df.plot` has an auto-adjustment function for dates. See this for [details](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html). To make each graph equivalent, modify the first graph as follows, `for c in df.columns:ax.plot(df.index, df[c], label=c)` and the second graph as follows.`df.plot(ax=ax, x_compat=True, rot=0) ` No locator settings are required for both.

Comment: that trick with `x_compat = True ` does work. Thanks for your answers.